# How many "drive by" viruses were discovered in the last couple of years?

Tags: windows-7, security, internet, browser, malware

I mean those that infect by only viewing a website or clicking a link. Not those that you have to click "Download" in the Windows dialog.

I want to know how important are virus definition updates in anti-virus software.

Comment: How important is it to get a regular pay cheque?

Comment: @Luke A pay cheque is used to buy things. An anti-virus definition update, if you don't download anything, is for... "drive by" infections. If a vulnerability in a main browser (Chrome or Firefox) is found once a year - you might be willing to use a free anti-virus suite.

Comment: @Startup1 What's wrong with a free AV suite?

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous lists and databases of exploits and vulnerabilities: [`exploit list`](https://www.google.com/search?q=exploit%20list), [`exploit database`](https://www.google.com/search?q=exploit%20database), [`vulnerability list`](https://www.google.com/search?q=vulnerability%20list), [`vulnerability database`](https://www.google.com/search?q=vulnerability%20database)

- [CVE](http://cve.mitre.org/) (Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures)
- [NVD](http://nvd.nist.gov/) (National Vulnerability Database)
- [OSVDB](http://www.osvdb.org/) (Open-source Vulnerability Database)
- [Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/modules/)
- [GFI](http://kbase.gfi.com/showarticle.asp?id=KBID002538)

As for “how important” it is to keep antimalware definitions updated, the answer is yes, I mean 17, wait, purple. No, monkey. No, no, it’s dishwasher. There is no answer to that question as there is no unit of measure. Suffice it to say that it *is* important.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice. One for a good answer and one for humor

Comment: Since you don’t know the answer to my question - how do you know that "it _is_ important."?

Comment: I *do* know the answer to your question, like I said the answer is `is`; there is no **measure**. You want to know *how much* important it is? What does that even mean? What exactly do you expect to hear? I said it is 17 important; does that work for you? No? Okay, fine I’ll add some units. It is 17 meters important. Good? How about 17 dollars important? Maybe 17 bytes important?